# Implementing Reporting Feature (Crystal Report) in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, crystal-reports, report

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC3.0 application and need to create some reports. I am not getting how i can integrate Crystal Reports or any other Free Reporting tool with MVC3.0 to implement reports. Could you let me know how can i generate reports in ASP.NET MVC3.0

Thanks.

Comment: For registered tools, You can contact tools owner. I m Sure there are code exaples on their web sites. And they should support to you about this topic.

Comment: do you know any specific reporting tool to be easily integrated with asp.net mvc3

Comment: I m Using DevExpress XtraReports. It is not free but it is very good options.

Comment: http://mvc.devexpress.com/Report/SideBySideReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this blog. The author explained step by step in visual representation.

http://kbochevski.blogspot.in/2010/01/aspnet-mvc-and-crystal-reports.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see this blog in which you can implement the crystal report in ASP.NET MVC razor.

http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2014/11/aspnet-mvc-sap-crystal-report.html